# useContext Returning Undefined Even Though It Shouldn't Be Undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, use-context

I have created the following context in React:

```
import { useBoolean } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { createContext, FC } from "react"

type useBooleanReturn = ReturnType<typeof useBoolean>

export const MobileContext = createContext<
  [show: useBooleanReturn[0], setShow: useBooleanReturn[1]] | undefined
>(undefined)

// --- PROVIDER
const MobileProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useBoolean()

  return (
    <MobileContext.Provider value={[show, setShow]}>
      {children}
    </MobileContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default MobileProvider
```

So far so good, but when I try and use this context it turns out that what is being passed down is `undefined`.  That is, in the following code `value` is undefined:

```
const value = React.useContext(MobileContext)
```

I don't know why that is, though, since I use the `useBoolean` hook when setting up the context -- i.e., this line:  `const [show, setShow] = useBoolean()`.  I then pass on `show` and `setShow` to my context with this line:  `value={[show, setShow]}`.  As such, shouldn't value be defined with an array with two values (namely `show` and `setShow`)?

Any idea why that is NOT happening and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Here is the full example of when I call `useContext`:

```
import * as React from "react"
import MobileProvider, { MobileContext } from "./context.mobile"

const Mobile = () => {
  const value = React.useContext(MobileContext)

  console.log("value:", value)
  ...
```

The above is what I did for testing purposes.  Here is what I the code is actually supposed to look like:

```
import * as React from "react"
import Base from "./base"

import Header from "./Header"
import Menu from "./Menu"
import Footer from "./Footer"


import MobileProvider, { MobileContext } from "./context.mobile"

const Mobile = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useContext(MobileContext)

  return (
    <MobileProvider>
      <Base onClick={setShow.toggle} ref={ref} show={show}>
        <Header onClick={setShow.toggle} />
        <Menu />
        <Footer />
      </Base>
    </MobileProvider>
  )
}

export default Mobile
```

Comment: Please show FULL EXAMPLE, where you actually call `useContext`, can you reproduce it in a codesandbox?

Comment: @DennisVash I have updated the question.  Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Still not a full example, how do you render `Mobile`? Please show the `MobileProvider` component tree

Comment: @DennisVash The Provider was supposed to be there (I had done an experiment where I moved the Provider higher up, but it didn't help).  Either way, I have re-edited the code with `MobileProvider` included.

Comment: But your `Mobile` component is clearly __above__ `MobileProvider` (it includes it). So it gets _default_ context value, not the actual provided by the provider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You suppose to call `useContext` on PROVIDER'S CONSUMERS.

In other words, the component which calls the `useContext` (`Mobile`) must be a child of `MobileProvider`.

In your case, its not a consumer, thats not how the API defined, therefore you will get the default value (`undefined`) since its called out of context.

```
const Mobile = () => {
  // NOT A CONSUMER
  const [show, setShow] = React.useContext(MobileContext)

  return (
    <MobileProvider>
      ...
    </MobileProvider>
  )
}
```

Move the component to `MobileProvider` tree

```
<MobileProvider>
  <Mobile/>
</MobileProvider>

const Mobile = () => {
  // NOW A CONSUMER
  const [show, setShow] = React.useContext(MobileContext)

  return (
    <Base onClick={setShow.toggle} ref={ref} show={show}>
        ...
    </Base>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- that solved the problem.  Much appreciated :).